# How to connect to spark from a PHP application?

Tags: php, apache-spark

how to connect to a spark cluster from a php application? we want to run spark sql queries and display the output in the web page. any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

you should check spark job server, it will provide you rest api for submitting spark jobs. I.e. your spark cluster will be installed elsewhere.